# Monitors blank after suspend on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, suspend, display

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit. Most of the time when I suspend and attempt to wake up the computer, the fans start moving and the tower light turns on (indicating that the CPU is running) but the monitors receive no signal. One time when I attempted to wake from suspend only my primary monitor displayed anything. I tried unplugging both monitors and plugging them back in, then they were both completely blank. This leads me to believe that the OS is somehow not recognizing my monitors after sleeping. However, most of the time the monitors receive no signal to begin with. The only thing that has been able to resolve this issue is a hard reboot. On a side note, is there any chance that my OS will become unbootable if I hard reboot too often?

Edit: It's definitely the monitors. I have recently been turning the monitors off when I am not using the computer. For no obvious reason, the monitors both said "no signal" even though I had only turned them off for several hours. This required a hard reboot.